# I'm trying to shift some elements in the navigation bar to right using twitter-bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to shift **login** and **cart** to right.I tried `mr-auto`, `ml-auto` `justify-content-between` and `justify-content-end` but out of vain it just doesn't shift right. What can I try next to resolve this?

```css
#header-nav
{
    background-color: #C5B358;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id=header-nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default justify-content-end">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <h1 class="tagline">Subha</h1>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Cart</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

[Navigation bar of my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aCks.jpg)

Comment: Hello, can you show the full code of this block?

Comment: Navigation bar's code is up to these only after this other body are there which are functioning normally.

Comment: s0xzwasd what did you meant by full code of this block I didn't quite understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ml-auto` to align **login** and **cart** to right.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Remove `justify-content-end`

```
<nav id=header-nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default">
```

```css
#header-nav {
  background-color: #C5B358;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id=header-nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand ">
    <h1 class="tagline">Subha</h1>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Cart</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ok I will do it in my pc and respond here

Comment: @Soumalya Bhattacharya, you need to open Full Page in order to see the login and cart shift to right.